Script is not recognizing file name format, even though it should?
I'm working on a script to take a file with a name format of "firstname lastname OL.pdf", copy and move it to a newly created folder of "firstname lastname", and delete the original file. I had someone help me out with this, however when I try the script, I keep getting an error of "Filename 'firstname lastname OL.pdf' does not match expected format. From my understanding, it shouldn't error out, but I may be missing something small as this is the first time I've tried working out a script. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the code I tried.
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

property cloud_folder : "/Users/will/Documents"


(*  There are three ways of invoking this script:
- as a folder action (automated)
- by running the script directly (as an app, or within Script Editor
- by saving it as an app and dropping a file on it
*)

on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    --  Called after items have been added to a folder
    --
    --  theFolder is a reference to the modified folder
    --  theNewItems is a list of references to the items added to the folder 
    
    repeat with each_file in theNewItems
        my handle_file(each_file)
    end repeat
end adding folder items to

on run
    -- called if the script is run directly
    -- prompt the user for a file to process
    handle_file(choose file)
end run

on open of theFiles
    --  Executed when files are dropped on the script
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        handle_file(aFile)
    end repeat
end open

on handle_file(theFile)
    tell application "Finder"
        set name_extension to name extension of theFile
        -- check if we have a pdf file
        if name_extension is "pdf" then
            -- we at least have a PDF file
            set filename to name of theFile
            try
                -- this assumes filename matches expectations ("first last OL.pdf")
                -- any other formats throw an error and need additional logic handling
                
                -- break out the filename into its components
                set {oldTID, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, space}
                set {first_name, last_name, OL} to text items 1 through 3 of filename
                
                -- check to match the 'OL' string in the filename
                if OL ≠ "OL" then error
            on error
                -- the file name does not match the expected format
                display dialog "Filename '" & filename & "' does not match expected format" with icon stop buttons {"Cancel"} default button "Cancel"
            end try
            set my text item delimiters to oldTID
            
            -- extract the applicant's name
            set full_name to first_name & space & last_name as text
            
            -- do we have an existing folder for this person?
            if exists folder full_name of cloud_folder then
                -- we do, so notify the user
                display dialog "Folder for '" & full_name & "' already exists" with icon stop buttons {"Cancel"} default button "Cancel"
            else
                -- make a folder for the applicant
                set new_folder to make new folder at folder cloud_folder with properties {name:full_name}
                --and duplicate the file there
                duplicate theFile to new_folder
                -- optional: delete the original file: uncomment the next line
                -- delete theFile
            end if
        end if
    end tell
    
end handle_file


The name of the file includes the name extension, so to work with just the part of the name without the extension you would need to extract it, for example:
set {fileName, name_extension} to {name, name extension} of theFile
if name_extension is not "" then set fileName to text 1 thru -((count name_extension) + 2) of fileName

Also note that the Finder doesn't know about POSIX paths, so those would need to be coerced using POSIX file.
